# Reader for MIME media type text/html; charset=UTF-8 was not found

Tags: java, android, ssl, jersey

Im trying to get a swagger-codgen generated jersey API library to fly with https (SSL).

It was working fine with only http like this:

```
  public ApiClient rebuildHttpClient() {
    // Add the JSON serialization support to Jersey
    JacksonJsonProvider jsonProvider = new JacksonJsonProvider(objectMapper);
    DefaultClientConfig conf = new DefaultClientConfig();
    conf.getSingletons().add(jsonProvider);
    Client client = Client.create(conf);
    if (debugging) {
      client.addFilter(new LoggingFilter());
    }
    this.httpClient = client;
    return this;
  }
```

But then I tried to set up SSL like this

```
public ApiClient rebuildHttpClient() {
    // Add the JSON serialization support to Jersey
    JacksonJsonProvider jsonProvider = new JacksonJsonProvider(objectMapper);

    TrustManager[] byPassTrustManagers = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {

      public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
        return new X509Certificate[0];
      }

      public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) {  }

      public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) {   }

    } };


    HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultHostnameVerifier();

    ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();

    SSLContext ctx = null;
    try {
      ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
      ctx.init(null, byPassTrustManagers, null);
    } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    config.getProperties().put(HTTPSProperties.PROPERTY_HTTPS_PROPERTIES, new HTTPSProperties(hostnameVerifier, ctx));
    config.getSingletons().add(jsonProvider);

    Client client = Client.create(config);

    if (debugging) {
      client.addFilter(new LoggingFilter());
    }
    this.httpClient = client;
    return this;
  }
```

It builds fine but when executed, I get this error

> A message body reader for Java class java.lang.String, and Java type class java.lang.String, and MIME media type text/html; charset=UTF-8 was not found
>   08-12 13:43:41.230 12544-12861/com.xxxxxx.app.xxxxx E/ClientResponse: The registered message body readers compatible with the MIME media type are:
>                                                                            */* ->
>                                                                              com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider

When executing this method in my ApiClient  (trying to authenticate)

```
 private void updateParamsForAuth(String[] authNames, List<Pair> queryParams, Map<String, String> headerParams) {
    for (String authName : authNames) {
      Authentication auth = authentications.get(authName);
    if (auth == null) throw new RuntimeException("Authentication undefined: " + authName);
    auth.applyToParams(queryParams, headerParams);
    }
}
```

When I test the server response with swagger-ui it shows that it is in the right type **application/json**

It seams to have something with the serverside to do? Becouse it worked fine a couple of days and then suddently the error cameback with out me changeing the code client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a issue on the server side. It seams to occur when the server have problems, I'm not the back-end developer so I can't tell what problem it was.

Answer (score 0):

The bits of code don't show what is actually done, but looking at the error message I would guess, that your client has tried to call the server and gotten a html response back. Your client doesn't know how to decode this response. I suggest you call the URL in a browser and see what happens.
It's likely that you are either calling the wrong url or that you might need to provide the authentication credentails in the call.

Comment: No the credentials are in place and I have tested it successfully against the mock API.